# Index on Date field in Calendar table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have a calendar table that has a list of all days frtom 01-JAN-1990 to 31-DEC-2050

That results in 22279 rows in my table.

A lot of queries we do, I join to the calendar as I need a list of dates based on certain data. For example:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Person A
INNER JOIN Calendar C
ON C.DateValue BETWEEN A.StartDate and A.EndDate
```

This is an example... but I'm looking for a list of the dates for the person, and a date column to come back.

What I'd like to know, is: Is the DateValue column a good candicate for an Index? And would there be ebefit of it being Clustered?

(SQL Server 2008 R2)

Answer (score 0):

No, the Date type columns is not good candidate. Columns which you want to choose should be more simple. like int or BigInt types.

Comment: But there's no foreign key or anything between the tables I am using. It's just a table of dates.

Comment: @Craig I am taking about a time the you have choices. In your case candidate is meaningless word.